# A single word that says a person (child) was taught one thing and has not been told about alternatives

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that means teaching or giving someone only one thing and not letting them know about other alternatives (e.g. teaching a child of only one religion?)

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Comment: Though the questions are not identical, the concept and answers are the same.

Answer (score 6):

[**Indoctrinate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indoctrinate) - to teach (someone) to fully **accept the ideas**, opinions, and beliefs of a particular group and **to not consider other ideas**, opinions, and beliefs

> Parents indoctrinate their children in their beliefs.

> Bobby became indoctrinated in catholicism; he's never been to any other kind of church.

Also, see the question, "[What is less harsh than 'brainwashing'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/292738/184551)" which is similar.

Comment: *home-schooled* ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that **indoctrination** has already been proposed, how about **programmed**?

[**programmed**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/programmed): caused to absorb or incorporate automatic responses, attitudes, or the like; conditioned